# Obtain Line Series Handle of Current Figure

Tags: matlab

Is there any equivalent of `gca` but instead I want to obtain the handle for a lineseries object (what is returned from `plot`).

I am using `candle` which does not return a handle, but would like to modify it's `XData`  aside from copying the code and modifying the function, is there a built in that will allow me to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably find that handle (along with many others) in the output of

```
get(gca, 'Children')
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution

```
fighandle = openfig('path of figure.fig','reuse')
ax=findall(fighandle,'Type','line');
x=get(ax,'Xdata')
y=get(ax,'YData')
```

if there are more than lineseries

```
xx=x(length(x),1);
xx=xx{1};
```